# Demonstration of $\int_{a}^b f(x) \,dx= 0 \Rightarrow f(x)\equiv0 $

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

Good morning,

Can you give me a help to demonstrate this proposition:

$f$ is a continuous and not negative function on the interval $[a,b] \ a,b \in \Re $,  Demonstrate:

$$\int_{a}^b f(x) \,dx= 0 \Rightarrow f(x)\equiv0  $$

Comment: Hint: Try proving the contrapositive.  If $f$ isn't identically zero, can you show that its integral has to be positive?

Comment: Personal input?

Comment: Thanks.It's a personal interest

Comment: Proof by contradiction makes it easy.

Comment: Your personal interest could be to try to follow the rules of the site. At present, you are not.

Comment: @Did Sorry, why ? Should I improve my question with other data? What does it mean "put on hold as off-topic"?

Comment: It means that "This question appears to be off-topic. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x) = \varepsilon 0$ for some $x \in [a,b]$. Because $f$ is continuous there exists $\delta$, that $f(y)=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0$ for $y \in [x-\delta,x+\delta]$, so:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{x-\delta}f(x)dx+\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f(x)dx+\int_{x+\delta}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Now $\int_{a}^{x-\delta}f(x)dx\geq0$ and $\int_{x+\delta}^{b}f(x)dx \geq 0$ because $f$ is non-negative, so:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \geq \int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f(x)dx$$

but $$f(y)=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0$$ for $y \in [x-\delta,x+\delta]$

so

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \geq \int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f(x)dx>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\cdot 2\delta >0$$

Answer (score 5):

Let

$$\Phi(t)=\int_a^tf(x)dx$$
then $\Phi'(t)=f(t)\ge0$ hence $\Phi$ is non-decreasing but since $\Phi(a)=\Phi(b)=0$, this means $\Phi$ is constant and $\Phi'(t)=f(t)=0$.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got $\Phi(a) = \Phi(b) = 0$? I understand why $\Phi(a) = \Phi(b)$ but not why they are $0$

Comment: @benji $\Phi(a)=\int_a^{a}f(x)dx$, for example what is $\int_2^{2}f(x)dx$? We have $\Phi(a)=0$ and $\Phi(b)=0$ then $\Phi(a)=\Phi(b)$. Nice proof +1

Answer (score -2):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]$, and the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are equal. It is fairly straightforward to show that a nonnegative measurable function has Lebesgue integral zero if and only if it is zero almost everywhere. Since we have the additional assumption that $f$ is continuous, if $f$ is zero almost everywhere, then necessarily $f$ must be identically zero.

I don't understand why I have 3 down votes for this answer and no comments...